# Token-Pasting (##) backslashes in C Macro

Tags: c, macros

I'm struggling to make a macro that used like this:

BYTE_AS_STRING(0A);

expands into:

"\x0A"

is it possible?

So far I've tried this:

```
#define STEP2(a)               #a
#define BYTE_AS_STRING(byte)   STEP2(\x##byte)
```

and:

```
#define STEP3(a)               #a
#define STEP2(a, b)            STEP3(\##a##b)
#define BYTE_AS_STRING(byte)   STEP2(x, byte)
```

Without success. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do that? Wouldn't is be simpler (and more readable) to just write `"\x0a"` when you mean it?

Comment: Hum... looking at the answers, I'm not sure what you actually mean now. Do you actually mean the macro to expand to "\x0a" or "\\x0a"? (I.e. line-feed, or literal `backslash x zero a`?)

Answer (score 1):

I shall say that I share  Joachim Pileborg's point of view.

Anyhow, here is what you need. You shall say to `cpp` to consider your macro parameter as a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTE_AS_STRING(x)   "\\x" #x 

int main(void) {
    printf("print this : %s\n", BYTE_AS_STRING(0A));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
#define S(a)   #a
#define X(b)   S(\x##b)
#define BYTE_AS_STRING(c)   X(c)

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%02x %s", (int)(BYTE_AS_STRING(0A)[0]), BYTE_AS_STRING(0A));
}
```

Pre-processed:

```
// ...
int main(void)
{
    printf("%x %s", (int)("\x0A"[0]), "\x0A");
}
```

Hexdump'ed output is as expected:

```
$ ./a.out | hexdump -C
00000000  30 61 20 0a                                       |0a .|
```

Comment: Thanks Mat, but it didn't worked in my compiler, I'm programming a microcontroller, although the compiler says it's ANSI C, I think it may be wrong. I know this question seemed rare, but I'm concatenating strings and I wanted to be insert bytes like this: "Hello" BYTE_AS_STRING(AA) "World" to get a concatenated string as it was typed like this "Hello \xAA World" knowing that I'm going to get the byte [0xAA] in memory instead of [Backslask] [x] [A] [A]